# Pass C# string to C++ pointer Char in typedef

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, typedef

I need pass a string of IP "192.168.1.1" from C# code to the typedef char pointer in DLL which written by c++. and I declare the char *pcAddrs like

```
char *pcAddrs;  //c++

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string ip  //C#
```

and declare open function

```
//c++
int Open( COMMIF_INFO *pInfo )

//c#
[DllImport("Open-IF.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Open(COMMIFINFO info);
```

Now i get an error of wrong parameter when press button1 to trigger the Open function. It is the string and char pointer wrong?

Thanks in advance.

C++ DLL info

```
typedef struct CommIfInfo
{
    char *pcAddrs;
    long lPortNo;
    long lRetry;
    long lSendTimeOut;
    long lCommSide;
    long lMode;
    long lKind;
} COMMIF_INFO;

//Function need to call.
int Open( COMMIF_INFO *pInfo )
```

Code in C#

```
    // DLL import
    [DllImport("Open-IF.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Open(COMMIFINFO info);

    // Structure
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]        
    public struct COMMIFINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string ip;
        public int PortNo;
        public int Retry;
        public int SendTimeOut;
        public int CommSide;
        public int Mode;
        public int Kind;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _ip = "192.168.1.1";
        COMMIFINFO info = new COMMIFINF();
        info.ip =  _ip;
        info.Kind = 1;

        int ErrCode = Open(info);
    }
```

Comment: "an error of wrong parameter" - what is the *exact* error message?

Comment: Strings are different in c# and c lanaguage.  In c# it is a class object.  In c language it is bytes terminate with '\0. Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi will automatically do the conversion.

Comment: `public static extern int Open(in COMMIFINFO info);` it needs to be an `in` parameter. Alternatively make the `struct` a `class`

Comment: Hi @Selvin  do you mean change to  "IntPtr _ip = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt16("192.168.1.1"));"  ?

Answer (score 0):

Program will get wrong parameter error if passing the COMMIFINFO using method below

```
[DllImport("Open-IF.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Open(COMMIFINFO info);
```

Found is because the parameter pass to open function need by reference. So program working if use "in" to pass parameter with reference.

```
[DllImport("Open-IF.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Open(in COMMIFINFO info);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).